# How to change Jenkins dev branch?

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed the devel_branch field of my Indigo release (https://github.com/rospilot/rospilot-release/blob/master/tracks.yaml), as it was previously tracking master. However, the Jenkins job (http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__rospilot__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/51/) is still tracking master instead of my indigo branch. How do I update Jenkins to use the new configuration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238328/how-to-change-jenkins-dev-branch?/) by [cberner](https://answers.ros.org/users/27327/cberner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The continuous integration uses the source definition from the rosdistro.

You should update the entry here: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/indigo/distribution.yaml#L10043

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cberner](https://answers.ros.org/users/27327/cberner/) on 2016-06-29**:
Ah, got it. Thanks!